# Debug Vue.js from parent directory

Tags: api, vue.js, visual-studio-code, node-modules

I started out by following microsoft tutoral [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-vue?view=vs-2022) which results in one solution and two projects (vue as frontend and api as backend)

Current setup:

- Vue 2
- .Net 6

It is located at C:/Projects/project_name

Directory layout:

`- project_name.sln (solution file)`

`-- project_nameFrontend (frontend)`

`-- project_nameBackend (backend)`

`-- .vscode`

The problem is when I open it in C:/Projects/project_name, some of the front end code will show error.
e.g. the following line will result in "couldn't find module @/helpers/interceptors"

`import { instance } from '@/helpers/interceptors';`

If I open in "C:/Projects/project_name/project_nameFrontend" (where node_module is), no errors.

I know the errors are due to npm, and the parent folder doesn't know where node_module is.
The reason I want to open it in parent directory so I can debug the API backend code as well as the front end at the same time.

Is there a work around for this?

Comment: You mention "some of the front end code will show error." Where is the file that throws this error located in your directory structure? More importantly, you also hint that "if I open." Do you mean mere opening through VSCode or running `npm run serve`, for example?

Comment: @RotikenGisa, the file is located under project --> project_nameFrontend --> src --> views --> someFile.vue. When I say "if I open" I mean simply opening in vs code --> File --> Open Folder --> Select the folder which contains both front and back end subfolders.